# Provision of OrbStack with Ansible

Tags: macos, ansible, ansible-inventory

The following problem:
OrbStack (Centos-8) is only reachable via "ssh orb".
This works 100% under zsh/OSX.
But no configuration of an Ansible inventory makes it possible to play a setup via Ansible on the Centos machine - e.g. to install Django on Centos.
The address "centos8.orb.local" is reachable via ping and returns "198.19.249.149". But neither "centos8.orb.local" nor "198.19.249.149" can be used in an inventory by Ansible.
Ansible is apparently not able to communicate with OrbStack.
Who knows the problem and found a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to get this to work so far is to adjust my ssh config file. An example is below.

Ansible is working for me against both of the VMs below.

```
Host webapps1.orb.local
  Hostname localhost
  Port 32222
  User webapps1
  IdentityFile ~/.orbstack/ssh/id_ed25519.orig
  PreferredAuthentications publickey

Host webapps2
  Hostname localhost
  Port 32222
  User webapps2
  IdentityFile ~/.orbstack/ssh/id_ed25519.orig
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Answer (score -1):

I just used `orb` as the hostname, and it works.

And maybe [this piece](https://docs.orbstack.dev/machines/ssh#connection-details) from the official doc helps.

> For apps that don't use OpenSSH, you can use the following connection details:
>
> Host: localhost
> Port: 32222
> User: default (or any of the examples above)
> Private key: ~/.orbstack/ssh/id_ed25519

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the query correctly, you want to use one of the Orbstack machines as the Ansible host.

It will not work since OrbStack is installed on your local machine. Not the ones created by OrbStack.

I was able to run Ansible from my Mac. Inventory was like this

```
machineNameOne@orb
machineNameTwo@orb
```